# Would replacing <?php get_sidebar(); ?> with the 'get_template_part' cause any problems?

Tags: php, wordpress

I know that the straightforward way of calling a Sidebar, within the WordPress Theme, is through the use of `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` with the `sidebar.php` file being saved within the Theme's root.

In the interest of improved organisation, I have created a folder entitled 'Sidebars' and then within this folder, created a series of templates for each Sidebar.

I have then called these within the theme as follows:

`<?php get_template_part( 'sidebars/sidebars-left-column' ); ?>`

Can anyone tell me if whilst my approach works, if it would cause me any problems at a later date and as such, should stick with `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>`

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely use that. The get_sidebar() function is just more conventional. And it can be used to call specific sidebars for your template.
ie :
You've got these sidebars (as files) :

```
sidebar-blog.php, sidebar-home.php, sidebar-page.php, sidebar-with_a_lot_of_ads.php...
```

you can call them respectively with

```
get_sidebar('blog'), get_sidebar('home'), get_sidebar('page'), get_sidebar('with_a_lot_of_ads')...
```

But more important, if someone else has to maintain your code, it's better to use conventions...

Comment: Thanks for this.  If I was to stick with the more conventional method, is there a way I could continue with placing the sidebar files into a sidebar folder and still have them called?  Via the conventional option, I can only seem to call the sidebars if they are saved in the theme root.  Is my only option, if I want to achieve this, to stick with the `get_template` route?

Comment: Once again, if you want to respect Wordpress structure, you have to put your sidebars files at the root folder of your theme. If you want to do something else, you'll have to use get_template_part and add a line of comment to let know the next dev (or you) that this is a sidebar (which should be obvious if you call a file in a sidebars directory ^^)

Here is the recommended organisation of a theme folder : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/organizing-theme-files/